# How to draw similar word's line chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Want to draw line chart. I1-I8 are on x axis and 61-64 values on y axis,
I1-63.37
I2-63.36
I3-63.34
I4-63.35
I5-63.41
I6-63.39[image: busavi]
I7-62.1
I8-63.19

Comment: `pgfplots` with `mark=diamond`.

Comment: Don't have any idea about drawing line chart. Can you please suggest with the code for reference?

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8},ymin=60.9,
ymax=64.1,xlabel=attacks,ylabel=PSRN in dB,ymajorgrids]
\addplot[mark=diamond*,color=blue] coordinates
{(I1,63.37)(I2,63.36)(I3,63.34)(I4,63.35)(I5,63.41)(I6,63.39)(I7,62.1)(I8,63.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot, please convert your comment to an answer :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am writing this not only to provide a technical answer to your question. This is also to inform you that some users do not feel that one should just add a screen shot and ask others to convert it to some TeX code that leads to that output. This is why your question has been closed. While I personally do not have strong opinion on this, I feel that it is nevertheless a good idea to first try something on your own. This has two advantages:

1. You learn more, so you depend less on others.
2. Others feel that their efforts are more appreciated.

In any case, here is a code that produces something reminiscent of your screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8},ymin=60.9,xtick=data,
ymax=64.1,xlabel=attacks,ylabel=PSRN in dB,ymajorgrids]
\addplot[mark=diamond*,color=blue] coordinates
{(I1,63.37)(I2,63.36)(I3,63.34)(I4,63.35)(I5,63.41)(I6,63.39)(I7,62.1)(I8,63.1)};
\addlegendentry{bus.avi}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I made this answer a community wiki such that others can take over more easily (if they want), and because I have been asked to do that.